# c# metro style app user inactive time trigering

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

i need to launch method when user is not active for specific amount of time

i have a timer which trigger the method, but i was trying to reset it in actions like:

```
ManipulationStarted, PointerPressed, SelectionChanged, Holding, ItemClick
```

here is my timer:

but nothing resets the timer:

```
public void timer_start()
{
    DownloadPromoted();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
    timer.Start();
}
```

here i reset my timer:

```
public void timer_stop()
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer_start();
}
```

is there a way to understand if user is doing something in metro app?

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested but i think you could do this.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += InputRecieved();

private Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler<Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs> InputRecieved()
{
    IsActive = true;
}
```